# How do I plot with matplotlib, called from a function?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I currently have a main script, calling a function. Part of that functions functionality is plotting two graphs. The script works if I include `show()` at the end, but it is a bit annoying that either the script pauses until I close the graph or I have to wait to look at the graphs until the program is finished. Hence I feel like I need to use `ion()`/`ioff()`. The code snippet below works if I call the function from the shell, but not if I call it from the script.

```
#Plot the graphs.
ion()
firstplot = plot(GridAround[Mode], LogTheory[Mode], '.')
secondplot = plot(GridAround[Mode], NormalApprox[Mode])
draw()
ioff()
```

My question is simply: How do I plot from within a function, without using `show()` (which will pause the script or only show the graphs at the end)?

I apologize in advance, this question surely must have an answer somewhere on the web, but after a couple of hours of searching, I have not been able to find it.

Comment: As it turns out, a solution that makes it work for me is:

    fig = figure()
    plot(blah)
    fig.show()

This does not halt the execution of the code, and allows the figure to be shown. However, the documentation on figure.show() is as far as I can tell virtually non-existent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different rendering [backend](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/howto_faq.html#generate-images-without-having-a-window-popup), however, you will need to save the plot as a file with `savefig` instead of using `show`

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

Comment: Saving the images is a solution, but not a very good one for my purposes.
However, figure.show() seems to be doing what I want.

Comment: @Har:  I'm glad you figured it out, I guess I misinterpreted what you were asking about.